# What does this notation mean? Functional Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I am studying analysis at the moment and came across this notation and I would like to know  what it really means:

$$C_{c}^{\infty}(\Omega)$$ My understanding so far is that,this is the space of compactly supported $C^{\infty}$ functions. What I don't understand is where the $\Omega$ fits into all this. Is it the domain or is it the space where the support of the function lies?

Thanks

Comment: It is where the domain is.

Comment: So, does this also mean that the compact support of any function in this space must be a subset of $\Omega$

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: actually it must be compact with respect to $\Omega$ (in the relative topology).

Comment: sorry could you explain what that means, i am really bad at topology and haven't studied it in great detail

Comment: Loosely speaking it means that you must be cautious... When you restrict yourself to doing analysis on an open subset of a bigger set, your family of compact subsets may vary, thus while saying that a set is compact, you usually say which topology you are referring to, unless it is intrinsicly clear from the situation.

Answer (score 0):

$C_{c}^{\infty}(\Omega)$ means smooth function with compact support in $\Omega$

Or $C_{c}^{\infty}(\Omega) =\{f : f\in C^{\infty}(\Omega) , spt(f) \text{ is compact & } spt(f)\subset \Omega  \} $

Warning: "Compact" and "Smooth" depends on which Topology you choose.

(In Analysis, most frequently-use Topology is induced by metric)

Comment: I think it would be clearer if you wrote $C^{\infty}_c(\Omega) = \{f \in C^{\infty}(\Omega) \mid \operatorname{supp} f\ \text{is compact}\}$.